# What's the cheapest way to upgrade from standard VS2008 to VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio

What's the cheapest way to upgrade from standard VS2008 to VS2010?

I looked on the web and it looked like they wanted a monkey for it (£500).
This seems steep for an individual wanting to upgrade using taxed money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still no upgrade pricing matching the $299 (VS2008) Standard -> (VS2010) Pro offer for devs in the States, our UK prices seem to not include this offer - at least not yet (see http://store.microsoft.com/microsoft/Visual-Studio-2010-Professional-Upgrade-Promo-for-VS-Standard-Users/product/BE303EE9?ref_ck=VS2010_StdPromo&WT.mc_id=VS2010_StdPromo).

A few are asking on ScottGu's nad Soma's blog about this, but so far no response from either unfortunately.

Comment: Priced at £269 in the UK - http://emea.microsoftstore.com/UK/en-GB/Microsoft/Visual-Studio-2010-Professional-Upgrade-for-Standard-Users

Answer (score 2):

According to Soma's website if you wait until the launch then you can get a special discount price :) - this should put the UK upgrade at around £270.

http://blogs.msdn.com/somasegar/archive/2010/03/01/new-offers-for-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Comment: Further to this, Soma has commented that the discounted "Standard Offer" will be available worldwide in the near future - http://blogs.msdn.com/somasegar/archive/2010/04/11/announcing-visual-studio-2010-and-net-framework-4.aspx#9995802

Answer (score 0):

There will be a free, express edition of VS2010.  You'll be missing some features, of course, but hey, it's free.  You can see a feature chart in the VS2010 Express Beta 2 section at the weblink below.

http://www.microsoft.com/express/downloads/

Comment: need resharper => need VS addins capability => need to pay.